# Opening port 3306 for Remote MySQL from VM

Tags: mysql, port, remote-access

I have a CentOS VM on my laptop running a Host-only and a NAT adapters.

I'm looking to connect to an external MySQL database on a Bluehost server. According to Bluehost the port 3306 is open.

When I run

```
nmap -v -sV localhost -p 3306
```

on my VM, it discovers open port 3306/tcp on 127.0.0.1.

I'm not sure if I want the port on 127.0.0.1 since my IP is 192.168.56.101? Not sure how to configure this further. Thanks in advance.

---

In iptables, I added these two lines:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --sport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

Not sure whether this was a destination or a source or both?! Is this even INPUT?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you mean. Are you running that `nmap` command on the Bluehost server? Or your VM? What are you actually asking? Can your VM not connect correctly to the MySQL DB on the Bluehost server. As an aside, make sure the DB is locked down on the server so that only your VM (or other authenticated users) can access the database. And that data is going over the wire encrypted.

Comment: I'm running nmap on the VM. Correct, my VM cannot connect to the MySQL DB on Bluehost. Not sure how to "lock down" the connection, although I'm pretty sure Bluehost handles that by allowing certain IPs.

Comment: I would strongly consider reading the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index.html) especially regarding [administering](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-administration.html) it and [security](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/security.html). The loopback device (127.0.0.1) is a special address and not accessible from outside. It is there to enable you to connect to MySQL using TCP from the same machine as MySQL is running on.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that 127.0.0.1 is not what I'm looking for. I tried opening the port on iptables. I'll edit the question and show you.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to grant privileges to allow a user to connect remotely as well as changing the bind-address in your /etc/mysql/my.cnf:

```
bind-address            = 127.0.0.1
```

Change it to:

```
bind-address            = 0.0.0.0
```

restart your mysql-server

```
/etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

0.0.0.0 means that you will listen on all interfaces.

Now to grant a user its rights to connect remotely:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE.* TO 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY "pass";
```

% means from any ip, if you only want to allow this for a certain IP, replace % with the ip.

Comment: I can run a mysqldump via SSH so I wouldn't think that this is an issue with Bluehost's configuration and Bluehost is telling me that the bind-address cannot be changed from 127.0.0.1. Is my iptables setup correctly?

Comment: Trust me, you need to change the bind address if you want remote connection. Unless you use a tunnel to your server, you will need this . I doubt that there are any rules blocking internal traffic present in your firewall. Please give me the output of iptables --list. If you run mysqldump through ssh you are basically running it on your server so there is no problem since you are listening on the local host.

Comment: iptables --list output: http://screencast.com/t/2YFpoP2BVl

Comment: If you provider does not allow you to listen on anything but your loop-back, then you will need to tunnel in as Lucas says... `ssh -L3307:localhost:3306 username@serveraddress` You can then `mysql -u mysqluser -p 3307` or point your sql tools to open localhost port 3307. This assume you are able to ssh into the remote server and that you have a locally running mysql server using port 3306

Comment: Your table defaults to accepting everything, so your firewall is not dropping anything. So you need to fix your firewall as well I'm affraid. If Blue Oyster don't want to change the policy then I'm affraid you are out of options. However tell me how you can run iptables on your VPS, but not be allowed to change the my.cnf on your own VPS...

Comment: That iptables --list output was from my local VM, not Blue Oyster. I'm in SSH right now but can't find the /etc/sysconfig/ folder.

Comment: Wait what ? Do or do you not have root on the vps you rent at blue oyster?

Comment: I do have root access but if I navigate to /etc/, I get this output: http://screencast.com/t/RuFeJBpteE

Comment: then why dont you just change my.cnf?

Comment: Apperently on CentOs it's /etc/my.cnf

Comment: I don't even see any bind settings in the file: http://screencast.com/t/gFqRTek5

Comment: @AlxVallejo Then you need to add it, changing 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0 or your VPSs IP **IS the ONLY way to access it other than on the box**

Comment: Add what I suggested, the bind address, BELOW [mysqld]

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to see the remote server port 3306 is open from your virtual machine, then this sounds like a MySQL configuration issue.  The MySQL instance on your other server is likely refusing your connection since it isn't a local connection.  This is the out of the box behavior with MySQL; it won't accept remote connections.

If you want to enable remote connections, try issuing the following from your MySQL instance:

`mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'yourUsername@xxx.yyy.zzz.aaa' IDENTIFIED BY "pass";`

This will allow the user, yourUsername to connect to the MySQL server from the IP address xxx.yyy.zzz.aaa.